# Auto smooth scrolling in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-handler, android-scroll

I use smooth `recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(int dx , int dy)` for scrolling.
Put this method in handler and call the `handler` every 50 miliseconds.
my speed range is `0 - 10`. 
`Runnable` of handle scrolling is

```
   private Runnable runnableMove = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0,speed * 4);
        handler.postDelayed(this,50);   
   };
```

Suddenly `scrolling` starts to `lagging`. And i must stop `scrolling` and start it again.

This is important and I sync 2 device and more (maybe 4 , 5) with the same item in `recycler view` and I need the scroll position of any of them to sync them together.

Most of the time one or two of the devices is slower or faster in scrolling. I need all device scroll with the same speed. How can I solve this problem in `android`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method and it works for me:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy, new LinearInterpolator(), time);
```

Comment: What dx  and dy here?

Comment: x = scroll value horizontally , y = scroll value vertically

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use an `ObjectAnimator`.

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(recyclerView, "scrollY", 1000).setDuration(12000).start()
```

Start this simultaneously on all devices and they should be in sync without any lag.